# How to get selected text in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that changes the selected text, and I have it assigned to a button.

It works perfectly when i run it directly from visual basic, but when I click the button, the button gets the focus and my text is no longer selected so the macro change the selected element to (button).

How can I select the text and run the macro by clicking on the button and still have the text selected?

Answer (score 4):

The way to do this is to set the set the `TakeFocusOnClick` property of the CommandButton to `False`. Here are is the code I use.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sel As Selection
    Set Sel = Application.Selection
    If Sel.Type <> wdSelectionIP Then
        MsgBox Sel.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the button embedded in the document? You may need to put it on a form that loads on top of the Word window or in a menu/toolbar, so that clicking it does not affect the selection in the document itself.

**Edit:**
I think you can use `Application.Selection.Previous` to get at what you need. You could use this to restore the selection after the click event, or to act upon that section of the document, or both.

I assume that this is available in previous versions of Word, but have only confirmed its presence in 2007.

Comment: Yes, the button is embedded into document. When i add button to top menu it works, but i have to use embedded button ( lecturer's request )

Answer (score 1):

You need to change TakeFocusOnClick to "False" in the Button Preferences.